# a tag href data with newlines

Tags: javascript, download, newline, vcf-vcard

I am using angularjs and am trying to create a system of downloading a vcard created in javascript. In order for the vcard to work on mobile, the data needs to be downloaded through an a tag. The problem is everytime I set the href="data:text/vcard, "+ string it saves the vCard but removes the newlines. vCards only work with newlines

Is there any way to keep the newline characters while saving data?

```
$scope.saveVcard = function(){
    var user = $scope.member;
    var out_string = 'BEGIN:VCARD\nVERSION:2.1\n\rN:' + user.last_name + ';' + user.first_name + ';;;\n\r'; //name
    out_string += 'FN:' + user.first_name + ' ' + user.last_name + '\n\r';//FN
    if (user.phone){
    out_string += 'TEL;CELL:' + user.phone + '\n\r';} //Phone
    if (user.email){
    out_string += 'EMAIL;PREF;INTERNET:' + user.email + '\n\r';}//Email
    if (user.prof_pic){
    out_string += 'PHOTO;PNG:'+user.prof_pic + '\n\r';}//picture
    out_string += 'END:VCARD';
           var a         = document.createElement('a');
           a.href        = 'data:text/vcard,' + out_string;
           a.target      = '_blank';
           a.download    = 'contact.vcf';
           console.log(a.href);
           document.body.appendChild(a);
           a.click();
           document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Comment: The proper newline sequence for vCards is "\r\n", not "\n\r". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha, I figured it out, simply use the function encodeURIComponent().

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
       a.href        = 'data:text/vcard,' + encodeURIComponent(out_string);
       a.target      = '_blank';
       a.download    = 'contact.vcf';
       console.log(a.href);
       document.body.appendChild(a);
       a.click();
       document.body.removeChild(a);
```